# add css class to <a> tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code

```html
<ul>
<li id="menu_house" class="main_menu "><a class="main_menu " href="searchHouse.php"><span>Houses</span></a></li>
<li id="menu_apartment" class="main_menu "><a class="main_menu " href="searchApartment.php"><span>Apartments</span></a></li>
<li id="menu_building" class="main_menu "><a class="main_menu " href="searchBuilding.php"><span>Buildings</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class to first `<a>` tag when page is loading, I know how to add `menu_house` `<div>`, like this:

```
$("#menu_house").addClass("selected");
```

**How can I add a class to the `<a>` tag?**

Comment: where is the problem? id are unique and you can add easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have multiple a tags with the main_menu class and you specifically want to add the class to the menu_house item:

`$("#menu_house > a").addClass("selected");`

Comment: This is actually the same as the accepted answer, only I answered it first. Oh well :(

Comment: this is also working. thank you very much. I'm very soory. this is my first question. I think I cant accept both.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#menu_house a").addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be:

```
$('ul li:first-child a').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

If `#menu_house` is always the first element use:

```
#("#menu_house a").addClass("selected");
```

If that's not the case use:

```
#("a.main_menu:first").addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `:first` pseudo class Like

```
$('a.main_menu:first').addClass("selected");
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/geKFy/